# python Discord Bot how to send messages from one channel to another

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel == (720020927668289588):
        await Bot.get_channel(703707652710072515).send(f"{message.author.name}: {message}")
    await Bot.process_commands(message)
```

I am trying to have the bot to when someone sends a msg in channel 1 it will send the message to channel 2
I When i type into channel 1 nothing happens and no msg is send to channel 2 and there is no errors in the console

I have got it sorted

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*?

Answer (score 0):

`message.channel` returns a channel object, you're trying to get the id. You can replace `message.channel` with `message.channel.id` to get the channel id. Then the code will work.

Comment: @MrToastre You have to enable intents, do so here: https://discord.com/developers/applications/